# 等号を使わないプロパティ値の設定と取得

Tags: vba

エクセル棒グラフの例：棒を網掛の表示にしてマクロ記録すると等号無しの例外的な記述になっているようです。（.Fill属性の表現の混在）

```
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Patterned msoPattern25Percent
End With
```

VBAで値を取得・設定するためにはコード中で等号を使うためエラーになります。
解決策をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: プロパティではなくメソッドのようですね。[Excel VBA 図形の塗りつぶしを設定するプロパティやメソッド](https://kosapi.com/post-3151/), [Excelグラフで特定のデータの色、透明度、テクスチャ、パターンを変更したり、戻したりする](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1410/07/news040.html), [エクセルVBAグラフ要素](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%ABvba%E3%82%B0/b891e907-a0c5-40ed-a88d-fb2842bbf744)

Answer (score 0):

**Patterned** はプロパティではなくメソッドです。
プロパティの方は **Pattern** で二文字短いですね。
どうも設定はメソッド、取得はプロパティのようです。

[FillFormat オブジェクト (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat)

> **メソッド**
>
> - Patterned
>
> **プロパティ**
>
> - Pattern

ちなみに構文部分は機械翻訳だけではなく原文もちょっと不思議な？内容になっています。
コピペして混じってしまったのでしょうか？
[FillFormat.Patterned method (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.patterned)

> 指定した塗りつぶしのパターンを設定します。
>   構文
>   式。パターン化(パターン)
>   **expression A variable that represents a FillFormat object.** 原文
>   式FillFormat オブジェクトを表す変数を取得します。 訳
>   パラメーター
>   名前  必須 / オプション  データ型    説明
>   Pattern 必須  MsoPatternType  パターンの種類を指定します。

[FillFormat.Pattern property (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.fillformat.pattern)

> 塗りつぶしのパターンを表す**msopatterntype クラス** 値を設定または返します。
>   構文
>   式。パターン
>   **expression A variable that represents a FillFormat object.**
>   式FillFormat オブジェクトを表す変数を取得します。
>   注釈
>   **塗りつぶし**** のパターンの種類を設定するのにには、パターン化メソッドを使用します。**

---

メソッドのパラメータとプロパティの値の説明が同じ文言になっているのが **「不思議な」** と書いた根拠です。
今まで厳密に細かい文言を見較べたことは無いので、MSではこれが普通なのかもしれませんが。

そしてメソッドである**Patterned**に対して`=`を使った取得・設定を行っても、それは両方エラーになるでしょう。(**式**とあるので取得は出来るのかも？)
`=`を使って取得・設定を行うなら**Pattern**プロパティを使わなければならないはずです。しかし注釈に「設定にはメソッドを使う」とあるので、仮に`Pattern = xxxx`で設定できたとしても、そうではなくてメソッドを使いましょう、ということだと思います。

とここまで書いてきてナンですが、どちらも使ったことは無いので、用語の仕様を基にした概念的な説明です。

提示されたコードは動くと思われます。
質問者さんは、`Patterned`がプロパティだと誤解して、設定・取得に `=` が使われていないのを疑問に思って `.Patterned = msoPattern25Percent` に書き換えようとしてエラーになった(さらに `xxxx = .Patterned` として取得を試してもエラーになった？)ので、この質問になったのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「原文もちょっと不思議な？内容」とありますが、どの部分のことでしょうか？ちなみに「訳」には原文にない「取得します」なんて言葉がつかされてて変ですが。(ドット記法の`.`が「。」になってたり…。)なお、質問者さんは「VBAで値を取得・設定するためにはコード中で等号を使うためエラーになります」と訴えているのですが、掲示されたコードを実際にExcelで実行してもエラーにはならない、と言うことなのでしょうか？

Comment: ***メソッドのパラメータとプロパティの値の説明が同じ文言になっているのが 「不思議な」 と書いた根拠です*** 別に厳密に細かい話じゃなく、どちらもドット記法の左側の`expression`が`FillFormat`型のオブジェクトでないといけない、と言っているだけなので、`FillFormat`型のプロパティやメソッドを記述している部分としては不思議なところは(原文には)まったく無いように思えます。後半の付加部分については明確化ありがとうございます。質問者さんにはこれを読んで何が起こっているのかもう少し明確化していただきたいところです。

Comment: その辺は、英語をGoogle任せにしている弊害ですかね。日本語表記がおかしいので、例えデータの内容が同じだとしても使われ方が違うので、説明の仕方は変えるべきと思い込んで、そうなっていなかったから書いたわけです。

Comment: 訳の方は不思議などころか完全な誤訳ですからね。文法的には単純な技術文でも、自動翻訳の結果を無闇にあてにしてはいけないと言う良い見本でしょうね。